# Histogram of an image but without considering the first k pixels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, histogram

I would like to create a histogram of an image but without considering the first `k` pixels.

Eg: `50x70` image and `k = 40`, the histogram is calculated on the last `3460` pixels. The first `40` pixels of the image are ignored.
The order to scan the `k` pixels is a raster scan order (starting from the top left and proceeds by lines).

Another example is this, where `k=3`:
[image]

Obviously I can't assign a value to those `k` pixels otherwise the histogram would be incorrect.
Honestly I have no idea how to start.

How can I do that?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectorized solution to your problem would be

```
function [trimmedHist]=histKtoEnd(image,k)
imageVec=reshape(image.',[],1);          % Transform the image into a vector. Note that the image has to be transposed in order to achieve the correct order for your counting
imageWithoutKPixels=imageVec(k+1:end);   % Create vector without first k pixels
trimmedHist=accumarray(imageWithoutKPixels,1);  % Create the histogram using accumarray
```

If you got that function on your workingdirectory you can use

```
image=randi(4,4,4)
k=6;
trimmedHistogram=histKtoEnd(image,k)
```

to try it.

EDIT: If you just need the plot you can also use `histogram(imageWithoutKPixels)` in the 4th row of the function I wrote

Comment: I really had not thought about turning the image into a vector.
Because I would like to see on screen the resulting image, I thought to turn the resulting vector into array `vec2mat (vecWithoutKPixel, width)` where `width` is the width of the original image.
There is a better way to do this? It's possible to do it?

Comment: @valerie What resulting image do you want to see? There is no resulting image, the image will be the same. You are just creating a histogram of the image which you can then see using `histogram`-function. But you don't change anything on the original image. You can of course turn the resulting vector (the histogram)  into an array of the width of your image, but it won't have the same length as your image then since the histogram has as many cells as you image has colours and the image array has as many cells as the image has pixels.

Comment: or do you want to see the image without the first k pixels? if so `k` must always be a multiple of the columns that your image has. Then you can plot the image without the first k pixels using `imshow(image((1+k/size(image,2)):end,:))`

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thanks, you have been very kind!

Answer (score 0):

One of the way can be this:

```
histogram = zeros(1,256);
skipcount = 0;
for i = 1:size(image,1)
    for j = 1:size(image,2)
        skipcount = skipcount + 1;
        if (skipcount > 40)
            histogram(1,image(i,j)+1) = histogram(1,image(i,j)+1) + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

If you need to skip some exact number of top lines, then you can skip the costly conditional check and just start the outer loop from appropriate index.

Comment: It can be achieved without using loops. Loops are slow.

Comment: Iterating on all pixels is slow. You can only iterate on number of gray scale values.

Comment: @TonyTannous you don't need any loops. See my answer

Comment: @Max I will check it later tonight. I am on my phone right now no pc/laptop here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vec =  image(:).';
Vec = Vec(k+1:end);

Hist = zeros(1, 256); 

for i=0:255
    grayI = (Vec == i);
    Hist(1, i+1) = sum(grayI(:));
end
```

First two lines drop the first k pixels so they are not considered in the computation.

Then you check how many 0's you have and save it in the array. The same for all gray levels.

In the hist vector, in the i-th cell you will have the number of occurance of gray level (i-1).

Comment: You should explain your code or  tell how it solves the issue. Probably that is why this had been flagged as low quality.